# I want to build a script CDN for my place of employment

Tags: javascript, cdn, web-hosting

I write a bunch of scripts (javascript, php, perl) for my work. Right now, people have to get the scripts themselves from our sharepoint, and then install it as either a bookmarklet or a greasemonkey script.

What I would like to do is to have a server that I could host all of these scripts on (js only, ofc), and then if I make a change/fix/enhancement to it, they don't need to reinstall it and it will be updated automatically.  What are some good choices for this?  Bandwidth will not be super excessive, as each script is probably 3-5kb and they are not run 24/7.

Could I use things like an EC2 instance to host them? How reliable are VPS providers(lowendbox.com, etc)?

Comment: If this can be done entirely over the local intranet, do it. I wouldn't involve any third party (Amazon) unless you are unable to set up something locally.

Comment: I am not sure of the capabilities of sharepoint, but it requires authentication and it would be bothersome to have to authenticate with each use.

Comment: If you ever need webhosting, try digitalocean.